# How do I keep the links from moving down when the subnavigation drops down?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a drop down navigation bar in HTML and CSS, but I'm having issues with it. At first, I couldn't get the submenus to be the same width as the buttons they dropped down from, so I set them to width:100% and the unordered list to be position: relative. That worked, but now when the submenus drop down, all of the links from the bar drop down also. I'm not sure if I'm explaining it right, but here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/21605/ (Hover over Chapter or Tech Ed to see the problem) Whenever I fix one problem, the other returns. What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="headercont">

<div id="navmain">
    <ul>
        <li class="link_nav"> <a class="title_nav" href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="link_nav"> <span class="title_nav">Chapter</span> 
            <ul class="sub">
                <li> <a href="">About</a></li>
                <li> <a href="">Officers</a></li>
                <li> <a href="">Advisor</a></li>
                <li> <a href="">News</a></li>
            </ul> </li>
        <li class="link_nav"> <span class="title_nav">Tech Ed</span>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li> <a href="">Classes</a></li>
                <li> <a href="">Teachers</a></li>
            </ul> </li>
        <li class="link_nav"> <a href="">Design Brief</a></li>
        <li class="link_nav"> <a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>      
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#header #mainnav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#mainnav ul .nav_link {
    float: right;
    width: 10%;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#wrapper #mainnav {
    color: #2B3A42;
}
#wrapper #headercont {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: left;
}
#navmain ul .link_nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
#wrapper #headercont #navmain {
    height: 30px;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: #151C23;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
#headercont #navmain ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
ul .link_nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #D9E5E8;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
.title_nav {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #D9E5E8;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.sub {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

ul .link_nav:hover {
    background-color: #D9E5E8;
}

ul .link_nav:hover .title_nav {
    color: #151C23;
} 

ul .link_nav:hover .sub{
    display: block;
    background-color: #5C6E90; 
}

.sub li:hover {
    background-color: #D9E5E8;
}

.sub li:hover a{
        color: #151C23;
}

.sub li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there.

Make the `.sub` dropdown list `position:absolute;` and it will stop moving everything around. Add and play with `top:0;` and `left:0px` values on `.sub` also, this will position it relative to the parent `<li>` and give the dropdown effect you're looking for.

https://jsfiddle.net/JohnDevelops/WW3bh/21609/

^ Ive added `position:relative;` to the parent `<li>` and `position:absolute;top:20px;left:0;` to the dropdown `<ul>`.